# Python machine learning pytorch test/train epoch results problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, epoch, pytorch-dataloader

Created a linear neural network for 3 labels classification. I defined the train and test loops
and then i ran them for 50 times printing results every 10 epochs. In each print the accuracy
of the test is often the same. How can it be the same?

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class NeuralModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(25,50),
            nn.Linear(50,50),
            nn.Linear(50, 3),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_stack(x)
        return logits

model = NeuralModel()
print(model)

X_train_tensor = torch.Tensor(X_train_std)
y_train_tensor = torch.Tensor(y_train)
X_test_tensor = torch.Tensor(X_test_std)
y_test_tensor = torch.LongTensor(y_test)

batch_size = 32
train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(X_test_tensor, y_test_tensor)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

epochs = 50
def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0
    all_preds, all_targets = [], []
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y.long())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        train_loss += loss.item()

        _, predicted_classes = pred.max(dim=1)
        all_preds.extend(predicted_classes.numpy())
        all_targets.extend(y.numpy())

    train_loss = train_loss / len(dataloader)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(all_targets, all_preds)

    return train_loss, accuracy

def test(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    all_preds, all_targets = [], []

    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y.long()).item()
            all_preds.extend(pred.argmax(1).numpy())
            all_targets.extend(y.numpy())

    test_loss /= len(dataloader)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(all_targets, all_preds)
    confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(all_targets, all_preds)

    return test_loss, accuracy, confusion_mat


for epoch in range(1, 51):
    train_loss, train_accuracy = train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.4f}")

    test_loss, test_accuracy, confusion_mat = test(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {test_accuracy:.4f}")
    print("Confusion Matrix:")
    print(confusion_mat)
```

RESULTS

```
NeuralModel(
  (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  (linear_stack): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25, out_features=50, bias=True)
    (1): Linear(in_features=50, out_features=50, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=50, out_features=3, bias=True)
  )
)
Epoch 1: Training Loss: 1.0222, Accuracy: 0.6897
Epoch 1: Test Loss: 0.9916, Accuracy: 0.6460
Confusion Matrix:
[[46  1 15]
 [16  7  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 2: Training Loss: 0.9527, Accuracy: 0.7433
Epoch 2: Test Loss: 0.9277, Accuracy: 0.7788
Confusion Matrix:
[[58  1  3]
 [14 10  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 3: Training Loss: 0.8982, Accuracy: 0.8352
Epoch 3: Test Loss: 0.8713, Accuracy: 0.8584
Confusion Matrix:
[[58  1  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 4: Training Loss: 0.8444, Accuracy: 0.8506
Epoch 4: Test Loss: 0.8187, Accuracy: 0.8584
Confusion Matrix:
[[58  1  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 5: Training Loss: 0.7867, Accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 5: Test Loss: 0.7695, Accuracy: 0.8584
Confusion Matrix:
[[58  1  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 6: Training Loss: 0.7517, Accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 6: Test Loss: 0.7251, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 7: Training Loss: 0.6944, Accuracy: 0.8697
Epoch 7: Test Loss: 0.6845, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 8: Training Loss: 0.6599, Accuracy: 0.8697
Epoch 8: Test Loss: 0.6476, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 9: Training Loss: 0.6122, Accuracy: 0.8697
Epoch 9: Test Loss: 0.6158, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 10: Training Loss: 0.5992, Accuracy: 0.8697
Epoch 10: Test Loss: 0.5869, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 11: Training Loss: 0.5786, Accuracy: 0.8697
Epoch 11: Test Loss: 0.5629, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 12: Training Loss: 0.5644, Accuracy: 0.8697
Epoch 12: Test Loss: 0.5436, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 13: Training Loss: 0.5227, Accuracy: 0.8736
Epoch 13: Test Loss: 0.5254, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 14: Training Loss: 0.5449, Accuracy: 0.8736
Epoch 14: Test Loss: 0.5123, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 15: Training Loss: 0.5187, Accuracy: 0.8736
Epoch 15: Test Loss: 0.4999, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 16: Training Loss: 0.5244, Accuracy: 0.8736
Epoch 16: Test Loss: 0.4921, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 5 19  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 17: Training Loss: 0.4657, Accuracy: 0.8812
Epoch 17: Test Loss: 0.4818, Accuracy: 0.8673
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 4 19  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 18: Training Loss: 0.4686, Accuracy: 0.8812
Epoch 18: Test Loss: 0.4725, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 4 20  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 19: Training Loss: 0.4382, Accuracy: 0.8812
Epoch 19: Test Loss: 0.4643, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 4 20  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 20: Training Loss: 0.4241, Accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 20: Test Loss: 0.4576, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 4 20  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 21: Training Loss: 0.4195, Accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 21: Test Loss: 0.4520, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 4 20  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 22: Training Loss: 0.4247, Accuracy: 0.8889
Epoch 22: Test Loss: 0.4475, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 20  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 23: Training Loss: 0.4162, Accuracy: 0.8889
Epoch 23: Test Loss: 0.4438, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 20  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 24: Training Loss: 0.4083, Accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 24: Test Loss: 0.4396, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 20  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 25: Training Loss: 0.4096, Accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 25: Test Loss: 0.4356, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 20  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 26: Training Loss: 0.4106, Accuracy: 0.8927
Epoch 26: Test Loss: 0.4317, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 20  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 27: Training Loss: 0.4289, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 27: Test Loss: 0.4315, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 21  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 28: Training Loss: 0.3843, Accuracy: 0.9004
Epoch 28: Test Loss: 0.4283, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 21  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 29: Training Loss: 0.3862, Accuracy: 0.9004
Epoch 29: Test Loss: 0.4253, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 21  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 30: Training Loss: 0.4483, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 30: Test Loss: 0.4236, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 21  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 31: Training Loss: 0.3959, Accuracy: 0.9042
Epoch 31: Test Loss: 0.4218, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 3 21  3]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 32: Training Loss: 0.3850, Accuracy: 0.9042
Epoch 32: Test Loss: 0.4203, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 21  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 33: Training Loss: 0.3851, Accuracy: 0.9004
Epoch 33: Test Loss: 0.4195, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 21  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 34: Training Loss: 0.3822, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 34: Test Loss: 0.4193, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 35: Training Loss: 0.4585, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 35: Test Loss: 0.4189, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 21  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 36: Training Loss: 0.3650, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 36: Test Loss: 0.4181, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 21  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 37: Training Loss: 0.3869, Accuracy: 0.9042
Epoch 37: Test Loss: 0.4179, Accuracy: 0.8850
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 21  4]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 38: Training Loss: 0.3831, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 38: Test Loss: 0.4184, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 39: Training Loss: 0.3523, Accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 39: Test Loss: 0.4178, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 40: Training Loss: 0.3615, Accuracy: 0.9080
Epoch 40: Test Loss: 0.4167, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 41: Training Loss: 0.3601, Accuracy: 0.9042
Epoch 41: Test Loss: 0.4178, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 42: Training Loss: 0.4075, Accuracy: 0.9080
Epoch 42: Test Loss: 0.4173, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 43: Training Loss: 0.3470, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 43: Test Loss: 0.4170, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 44: Training Loss: 0.3658, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 44: Test Loss: 0.4171, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 45: Training Loss: 0.3518, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 45: Test Loss: 0.4168, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 46: Training Loss: 0.3445, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 46: Test Loss: 0.4166, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 47: Training Loss: 0.3592, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 47: Test Loss: 0.4189, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 48: Training Loss: 0.3484, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 48: Test Loss: 0.4194, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 49: Training Loss: 0.3396, Accuracy: 0.9080
Epoch 49: Test Loss: 0.4191, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
Epoch 50: Training Loss: 0.3463, Accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 50: Test Loss: 0.4208, Accuracy: 0.8761
Confusion Matrix:
[[59  0  3]
 [ 2 20  5]
 [ 2  2 20]]
```

shouldn't the results be more varied?

Model has to be with linear activation function, cant use any method to solve the imbalance in the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have N data points, the accuracy resolution cannot be less than 1/N, since changing the prediction on 1 data point while leaving all the other predictions unchanged affects the accuracy by 1/N.

In your case, it seems that you have an accuracy resolution in the test set of 0.0088 - 0.0089. Since you have 113 data points in the test set (from the confusion matrix you have 59+3+4+20+3+2+2+20=113 data points), the resolution cannot be less than 1/113 = 0.0088.